# Redirect from Default.aspx to root using IIS7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

When request comes to www.example.com/default.aspx, I want it to 301 to www.example.com. How to do that?

PS - I tried many rules but nothing seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using URL Rewrite with the following rule:

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="(.*)default.aspx" /> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```