# Removing page name from URL

Tags: .net, url

I have a .net 2.0 webforms based website and its hosted in IIS6. Below is a requirement for my home page

When I give my homepage url  for ex: www.mytestsite.com, I am served a default document. My current default document is default.aspx. So my browser url stays at www.mytestsite.com

Now when I give the full url like www.mytestsite.com/default.aspx I want my browser still to show as www.testsite.com/ and  not as www.testsite.com/default.aspx

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are already answers for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085860/redirect-from-default-aspx-to-root-using-iis7, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609763/redirecting-default-aspx-to-root-virtual-directory

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="(.*)default.aspx" /> 
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```